# DAX query to fill out a column based on a certain condition

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables T1 (id,c1) and T2(id,a,b). I want to fill in values(0,1) for "c1" in T1.

Condition: If 'id' is present in T2 then fill row for 'c1' as '1' else '0'

What should be the DAX query for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below expression for the `c1` calculated column in the `T1` table:

```
c1 = IF ( SUMX ( FILTER ( T2, [id] = EARLIER ( T1[id] ) ), 1 ) > 0, 1, 0 )
```

Comment: why did you use SUMX here?

Comment: @rahul, I prefer use SUMX over COUNTROWS both work in this case.

Comment: I want to enter the value of c1 as '1'  if minimum one row of the same 'id' exist in T2. So basically its boolean 1 or 0.  In this case do I need to add sumx or countrows? I don't need total count of all the rows with same id.

Comment: @rahul, did you even try the expression I posted?. It works also if only one row with the same `id` exists in T2.

Comment: Just tried. It works. Thanks :)  I just wanted to understand the use of sumx in my case. would it work even without using it? (Sorry I am new to this , just want to learn)

Comment: @rahul, The expression takes each row in T1 and every time it finds a common id in T2 it sum 1, when all rows in T2 are processed it checks if the result of the sum is greater than zero, if so there is at least a common field so fill the column with 1 otherwise it fills it with 0, then goes to the next row in T1 and so on.